# matrix build in one function and using in another function?

Tags: function, matrix

How can we use a matrix, which is saved in one function and we have to use it in another function?
both are separate functions in c .

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the language you're using, but normally you'd either return it from the "one function", or use an output parameter (also in the "one function"); and then pass it as an input parameter to "another function".

E.g. in C you would create a matrix and return it using something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>   /* malloc, free */

Matrix* create_matrix(...) {
    Matrix* res = (Matrix*) malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (res == NULL) exit(1);
    /* fill your matrix with initial data here */
    return res;
}
```

then pass it as an input parameter to use it, e.g.:

```
Matrix* mymatrix = create_matrix(...);
other_function(mymatrix);
free(mymatrix);
```

other_function would be defined something like:

```
void other_function(Matrix* m) {
    /* use m here */
}
```

Comment: but in my case i have to use these values of matrix in entirely different function. so values of matrix generated in one function has to be used in other function.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you found the answer helpful, you should  give it an up-vote.  If it solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer.  This will help future users by making it easier to find helpful answers (and it will give points to the person who answered your question -- looking at your profile, you really ought to do this for the other questions you've asked too!)